# Writing Makefile to separate tests from source code in Python

Tags: python, testing, makefile

I'm working on a project and have all of my source code in a subdirectory called `src/`. I've written a bunch of tests (this is all in Python, by the way) that require importing files that are in `src/`. Ideally, I'd like to have a separate subdirectory `tests/` at the same level as `src/` so that I can store my tests there instead. Unfortunately, the test files need to be in the same subdirectory as the source files to import them under this scheme. I know that this can be achieved using a Makefile, but am not too sure on how to write that. Could anyone help me out? I believe that you just need to change the file path.

Comment: Take a look to tox  (https://testrun.org/tox/latest/) - this is probably what you looking for, the issue with imports can be easily solved with PYTHONPATH (https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: I don't know Python, but I know that you can't do anything with Make unless you know how to do it *without* Make.